# Buoyant force on a certain object

Tags: forces, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Sometimes a certain body is completely immersed in water, but it does not sink deeply, it is stuck in the middle... In this case, is the buoyant force equal to the weight of the body? Why?

Comment: Please don't ask *"Yes/No"* questions, since *Yes* and *No* are too short to even submit as an answer. What do you want to know about the *physics* of this situation?

Comment: What is the value of upthrust force compared to the weight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Forces are bouoncy $B$ up and weight $W$ down. Newton's first law: $\sum F=B-W=0$. If no other forces apply, these must be equal, yes.